# why can't we bend a ruler along its breadth?

Tags: forces

We can bend a ruler easily along its length like if we keep it horizontally but why are we not able to bend it when we keep it in a position in which the plane of the ruler faces us and we apply forces along its breadth.

Comment: It depends on the material of the ruler. There are certain cheap wobbly rulers that do bend like this (don't buy them for obvious reasons)

Answer (score 5):

You need to look up the concept of [Area Moment of Inertia, also called the second moment of area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area).

Imagine the ruler to be made of fibers and think of a cross section to calculate the force and torque exerted by the parts of the ruler on either side of the cross section on each other through these "fibers" that run along the ruler's length, normal to the cross section.

You bend the ruler any way, and the fibres above a certain axis through the cross section - called the neutral axis - are stretched whilst those below the axis (nearer to the centre of curvature) are squashed. Each of the forces - tensile or compressive - of these "fibers", transmitted by the fibersbetween each of the two sections of the ruler - has a moment about the neutral axis.

If the thinnest part of the cross section is in the plane of bending, then none of these fibres are very far from the neutral axis. They therefore cannot exert very much torque for a given tension / compression, so the cross section cannot withstand bending very well and is thus "flimsy".

However, if the plane of bending is orthogonal to this, many of the fibres are a considerable distance from the neutral axis. This means that  even in a mild state of compression / tension, the two sections of the ruler can exert high torque on one another the resist bending.

Answer (score 0):

You can bend a ruler in any direction. How much depends on Young's modulus. If the movement is very little it may be almost imperceptible but it will be there. If you push on the wall of a skyscraper, it bends. The amount of bend is probably immeasurably small but it will bend. The ruler is much thicker along its breadth than height so you are bending much more material. Same force is trying to bend about 20 times as much material. A bending force that will easily bend a ruler through its height will cause a very very slight bend along its breadth. Try it. Get someone to hold a ruler down on a table on edge very firmly holding it on one end only or better clamp it in heavy vice on one end. Pull up the free end along its breath very firmly and may notice it bend by about 1 or 2mm. Very slightly but it will.